# How to apply onTap event to RadioListTile?

Tags: flutter

I have a popup dialog with a list of radio buttons that I wish to pop whenever a radio button is selected regardless of whether it is currently selected or not.

Using the Radio or RadioListTile widget included in the flutter framework only allows for the [onChanged](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RadioListTile/onChanged.html) event, which only fires off if there is a change. This means that if an item is already selected, the dialog will not be popped.

The [toggleable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RadioListTile/toggleable.html) property, is just that, a property, and does not allow for additional instructions to pop the dialog. It simply has an internal toggle that deselects the value.

I tried wrapping the RadioListTile with a GestureDetector which did not work, because the child (ListTile) of the RadioListTile has the tap priority.

There are other third packages that does this better but I would prefer to stick to the built in widget as much as I can.

Any help is appreciated. See below snippets of the code:

```
RadioListTile<Folder>(
  value: controller.folders[index],
  groupValue: controller.selectedFolder.value,
  onChanged: (newValue){
    // This callback is not invoked when an item is already selected
    controller.selectedFolder.value = newValue ?? controller.folders[0];
    // I'd like this to be called even if item has not changed
    Get.back(result: controller.selectedFolder.value);
  },
  title: Text(folder.isEmpty ? 'None' : folder.name),
)
```

Comment: `onChanged` triggers a callback when you select the radio button because thats what radio button is for. You may use checkbox instead and customise it accordingly to your needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may set `toggleable` to `true` and update only when the new value is not `null`. E.g.

```dart
RadioListTile<Folder>(
  value: controller.folders[index],
  groupValue: controller.selectedFolder.value,
  toggleable: true,
  onChanged: (newValue) {
    if (newValue != null) {
      controller.selectedFolder.value = newValue;
    }

    Get.back(result: controller.selectedFolder.value);
  },
  title: Text(folder.isEmpty ? 'None' : folder.name),
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You saved me from another GestureDetector. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i made this widget based on **khw147** comment

```
class RadioListTileClickable<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final T value;
  T groupValue;
  final ValueChanged<T>? onClicked;

  RadioListTileClickable(
      {super.key, required this.title, required this.value, required this.groupValue, this.onClicked});

  @override
  State<RadioListTileClickable<T>> createState() => _RadioListTileClickableState<T>();
}

class _RadioListTileClickableState<T> extends State<RadioListTileClickable<T>> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RadioListTile.adaptive(
      toggleable: true,
      title: Text(widget.title),
      value: widget.value,
      groupValue: widget.groupValue,
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          widget.groupValue = value ?? widget.value;
        });
        widget.onClicked?.call(widget.groupValue);
      },
    );
  }
}
```